# error al importar javafx eclipse

Tags: java, windows, javafx

hola llevo un par de dias intentando instalar javafx pero me da error a la hora de importarlo y no se por que ya he instalado todo lo que vi en el tutorial y no parece que vaya a funcionar[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui adjunto tammbien el codigo y el error que me da es:

> The import javafx cannot be resolved

```
package application;
    
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: ya lo añadi todo

Comment: ¿Agregaste `jfxswt.jar` y `jfxrt.jar` al proyecto?

Comment: como? nunca vi nada de eso solo me descarge el jfx de la pagina lo agrege al proyecto como decia el tutorial pero nada nmo funcionaba y esos archivos no me suenan

Comment: Hay varios tutoriales de JavaFX, no mencionas exactamente cuál ni la versión de JavaFX. Pero en general hay dos formas: 1) Agregando jars al proyecto 2) Usando un plugin para el IDE. Por lo que comentas, intentas con e(fx)clipse ¿Correcto?

Comment: he probado a descargar javafx desde el marketplace de eclipse y nada luego probe a bajarme los jars y añadirlos al proyecto y nada tampoco y me he dado cuenta que en clase hay un par que solo descrgandolo del marketplace ya les funcionaba pero ni a mi ni al 80% de la clase incluido la profesora nos funciona y ni ella sabe como solucionarlo

Comment: Por eso la conveniencia de saber más detalles como Sistema Operativo y las versiones de Eclipse, JDK, Java FX SDK, etc.

Comment: podemos hacer una llamada y lo hacemos? esque son muchas cosas y algunas no se como verlas

Comment: uso windows 10 pro, eclipse 2019-12, el jdk creo que es el 12, el java fx es el que hay actualmente en la workshop de eclipse no se cual es la version exactamente

Comment: En *Window>Preferences>Java>Installed JREs* ¿Cuáles tienes? Dinos *Name,Location y Type* y de propiedades del proyecto ¿Qué tienes en *Java Build Path>Libraries*?

Comment: he conseguido importar los jars pero ahora cuando ejecuto la app me salta el sgiuiente error:

Comment: Error: Could not find or load main class application.Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application

Comment: y la cosa es que no entiendo que puede faltar pues ya no da el error de que no puede importar sino que da que todo esta bien y me salta el error ejecutando el porgrama